# Why is banner not visible in my application?

Tags: java, android, admob

I am trying to add a banner in my application but it is not showing. I have a game that covers the screen and I have tried to add a banner in the bottom. I have followed these guides https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start / https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner aswell as the Tools-> Firebase -> Add Admob banner. I have also tried creating a separate activity for the ad in Android Studio so I have then inserted the code in another .xml and .java file apart from the rest of the code but the banner is still not visible. I do not know how to make the banner appear in the application. I have tried this code in another project so I suspect the game is "covering" the banner. Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />
```

//in separate activity xml.file and the banner shows up in preview. The banner does not show up if I put this code in the other xml file

```
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

//in strings.xml

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

//added in Google Admobs Activity along with various import command that are necessary

Comment: You should initialize your adView in the code not in the xml , and also sometimes the banner is not visible  because of the debug version , or because there is nothing to show adload error 3 , check your debugger messages

Answer (score 0):

Have you update your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In your XML,I think you missing this line,add this:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

So the XML look like this

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" //THIS LINE 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I missed adding that code in my post but yes I have and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `adView` in the code not in `xml` file since you initialized your `adMob` in the code aswell .

Sometimes the banner is not visible  because of the debug version , or because there is nothing to show adload error 3 , check your debugger messages

Comment: ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" . Is it this part that needs to be initialized? How would I do that? With a command similiar to         MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
but with app ID instead and replace "MobileAds"? How would I initialize it in my code? Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: No leave MobileAds.initialize() , and and initialize your adview like this :
adView.setAdUnitId(your_ads_unitid)

Comment: Just returns an error message "error: non-static method setAdUnitId(String) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: You should do it in onCreate() method within your activity